# Izpack Internationalization of Custom Information

Tags: java, xml, izpack

I have a question reffering to Izpack Internationalization.

- The default language I'm using is English. But if the user selects Romanian, I want to add internationalization to every custom element in the installer.
- FOR EXAMPLE:

  ```
  <panel order="0" id="xx">
          <field type="radio" variable="packageType">
          <description align="left" txt="Choose your module type:" id="module.description" />

          <spec>
              <choice txt="Choice 1"  value="English Text 1" />
              <choice txt="Choice 2"  value="English Text 2" />
          </spec>
          </field>
  </panel>``
  ```

** I want to change the value of the english text to romanian.

Researching IzPack, I tried to add a CustomLangPack.xml_rom

```
<langpack>
    <str id="module.description" txt="Alege tipul tau de afacere:"/>
</langpack>
```

- HOWEVER, this does not work.

How can I do this, without using static variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm back. After hours and hours of battle it finally worked.

How I did it:

- Defined a new resource called "userInputLang.xml_rom"
- Added values for the fields who needed to be internationalized

  http://izpack.org/documentation/user-input.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [docs for internationalization](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Internationalizing+resources), you need to add more than just that one file.

To quote:

> For instance let's suppose that we use a HtmlInfoPanel. Suppose that we have it in English, French and German. We want to have a French text for french users. Here we add a resource pointing to the French text whose name is HtmlInfoPanel.info_fra. And that's it! English and German users (or anywhere other than in France) will get the default text (denoted by HtmlInfoPanel.info) and the French users will get the French version. Same thing for the other Licence and Info panels.

Assuming that you are trying to customize the messages, which is based on your choice of adding the `CustomLangPack.xml_rom` file, then you need to add the `CustomLangPack.xml_rom` file, *and* you need to modify `install.xml`.

As an aside, the [3 country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) for Romania is `ROU` and not `ROM`, `ROM` is the old country code, however IzPack seems to be using the old `ROM` code, so that is OK ;-)

Comment: ISO3 file not found: /usr/local/IzPack/bin/langpacks/installer/rou.xml